# How to find if a Bare Metal is using any supported hypervisor (virtualization option)?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

We are starting to look if SoftLayer API has any service to find what hypervisor option is being used by a Bare Metal, is there any that you can suggest ?

Ideally we would like be able to identify if a Bare Metal is using VMWare, WindowsOS with Hyper-v, Citrix XenServer, etc so we can start reviewing if these has VM guests.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/getVirtualizationPlatform

This an example using REST:

```
GET https://$username:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Hardware/$hardwareId/getVirtualizationPlatform
```

(change credential values $username/$apiKey token, and specify your BM server id on $hardwareId value)

However I am not sure if the method is going to work for all your scenarios.

Comment: Thanks Nelson, this worked but as you pointed will not be useful for all our scenarios but it's beginning, let us continue exploring this.

Comment: I said I am not sure because I've never used it before

Comment: You can test all you possible scenarios and see if it works

Comment: Yes, No problem, it's what I have understood. Thanks!